# MYSQL : Unable to determine if daemon is running: Inappropriate ioctl for device (rc=0)

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

Need some help. How can I fixed this issue upon running using docker compose.

```
2020-08-10T08:24:49.653807Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) initializing of server in progress as process 44
2020-08-10T08:24:49.664010Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-08-10T08:24:52.877117Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-08-10T08:24:57.629900Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-08-10T08:25:03.057763Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 91
2020-08-10T08:25:03.106631Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-08-10T08:25:04.594295Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011065] [Server] Unable to determine if daemon is running: Inappropriate ioctl for device (rc=0).
2020-08-10T08:25:04.594313Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
2020-08-10 08:25:04+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Unable to start server.
```

Comment: Did you run it with memory swapping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We fixed this by increasing the memory limit of 256M that we had configured on the container, to 512M.